# How i create CRUD with relationships in cakephp3

Tags: cakephp, relationship, crud, cakephp-3.0

How i do a crud with a relationship between a user and services order? With the code, i can't add users in a team for service order. When cakebake, the controller TeamHasUsersController is created, but the form add don't have any field.

[image]

The crud has generated with cake bake.

[image]

Comment: Too much code is as bad as not enough code... you should really only include the relevant code parts. Also please elaborate on the actual problem that you are facing, stuff like "_doesn't work_" is not a proper problem description.

Comment: Edited with some details, @ndm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of table with associations should be "team_users".

> Three database tables are required for a BelongsToMany association. In the example above we would need tables for articles, tags and articles_tags. The articles_tags table contains the data that links tags and articles together. The joining table is named after the two tables involved, separated with an underscore by convention. In its simplest form, this table consists of article_id and tag_id.

[habtm relationship](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#belongstomany-associations)

Answer (score 0):

In service_orders: change requester_users_id into user_id, the icon in front of the field will change to a red key (foreign key). Cake conventions need a foreignkey to be named [model]_id.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but in that schema, how i do add users in a team?